# Forming a generic line between two points of a sphere

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, analytic-geometry

Consider the unity sphere $S^1=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \, | \, x^2+y^2=1\}$. I want to show that if $p,q \in S^1$ then $S^1 \setminus \{p,q\}$ is not connected.

My idea is to take the line formed by $p$ and $q$ and showing that the part over and the part under the line forms a non-trivial spliting of $S^1$. But my question is:

Given two generic points $p,q \in S^1$, how can I define a generic equation of that line?

Comment: Well, if you have the two distinct points $p=(x_0,y_0),q=(x_1,y_1)$, the line passing through $p,q$ has equation $\frac{x-x_1}{x_0-x_1}=\frac{y-y_1}{y_0-y_1}$

Answer (score 1):

The implicit equation of a line by two points is

$$\vec{ps}\times\vec{pq}=0$$

where $s$ is any point on the line.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use the fact that $S^1\setminus\{p\}$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$. It follows that $S^1\setminus\{p,q\}$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$ minus one point. And $\Bbb R$ minus one point is disconnected.

Comment: Actually, in my book that is an exercise before it defines that homeomorphism, so I have to solve it without using the given homeomorphism.